# Why is the copy constructor being used instead of the assignment operator

Tags: c++

This is how `MyClass` is defined:

```
class MyClass {
    double x, y;
    public:
        MyClass (double a = 0., double b = 0.) {
            x = a;
            y = b;
            cout << "Using the default constructor" << endl;
        }
        MyClass (const MyClass& p) {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            cout << "Using the copy constructor" << endl;
        }
        MyClass operator =(const MyClass& p) {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            cout << "Using the assignment operator" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

And I tested when each constructor or method is called in my main program:

```
int main() {
    cout << "MyClass p" << endl; MyClass p; cout << endl;
    cout << "MyClass r(3.4)" << endl; MyClass r(3.4); cout << endl;
    cout << "MyClass s(r)" << endl; MyClass s(r); cout << endl;
    cout << "MyClass u = s" << endl; MyClass u = s; cout << endl;
    cout << "s = p" << endl; s = p; cout << endl;
}
```

Why is the copy constructor being used in the fourth example, `MyClass u = s`, instead of the assignment operator?

**EDIT**

Including the output, as asked:

```
MyClass p
Using the default constructor

MyClass r(3.4)
Using the default constructor

MyClass s(r)
Using the copy constructor

MyClass u = s
Using the copy constructor

s = p
Using the assignment operator
Using the copy constructor
```

Comment: Because the language specifies that `Type var = value` invokes `Type`'s copy constructor and not its assignment operator.

Comment: Including the output of your program would be good.

Comment: Note that copy constructor need not be called at all. The compiler is allowed to optimize it away (see [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)). This is an exception to the rule that compiler optimizations do not change the observable behaviour of the program (`cout` statements in your case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because is not an actual assignment since you declare u at the same time. Thus, the constructor is called instead of the assignment operator. And this is more efficient because if it wasn't for this feature there would have been the redundancy of calling first a default constructor and then the assignment operator. This would have evoked the creation of unwanted copies and thus would had deteriorate the performance of the C++ model significantly.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the declaration and initialization of a variable, not the assigment of a value to an existing variable. In the context of a variable declaration, = is just syntactic sugar for passing a parameter to the ctor.

Comment: so the use of the assignment operator is always linked to the existence of a previously declared object?

Comment: @dabadaba yes. Assigment means giving a new value to an existing variable. Giving a value to a new variable is initialization, which is the work of ctors.